# Probability for a family of submultisets?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a multiset, e.g. something like A=[a,a,a,b,b,c] and I want to know the probability/frequency of the family of submultiset B=[x,x,o] where the *x's* means equal elements and the *o* means a different element... I want to know the frequency of this family of submultisets composed by a pair of equal elements and a different one.

I understand by probability/frequency the number of possible submultisets with this composition compared to all possible submultisets of cardinality 3. Think multiset A as a "bag" where I take 3 random elements and I want to know the probability for this random submultiset had the composition that I said above.

More precisely... exist a way to evaluate these type of probability without the use of the bruteforce to know all the possible valid combinations and it frequency?

Comment: When you say "without brute force", do you mean without using something like $\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1} +\binom{2}{2}\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{6}{3}}$? I assume that you use a uniform distribution?

Comment: @G. Bach, "without brute force" for me is that I can write something close to a general formula for any multiset or submultiset not just a algorithm for the example above. This is my idea about it. Why you say "uniform distribution"? The distribution is declared in the composition of multiset or submultiset... I dont understand this point. I dont want an abstract level of distribution out of the multiplicity declared on these multisets or submultisets.

Comment: @G.Bach, anyway show your formula if you want, I want to see all approaches to understand different ways to see this problem. I dont care if a numeric solution but I prefer something more symbolic related to things as cardinality or multiplicity. Anyway I will appreciate any light on this question.